# Penalized gamma regression in R

Tags: r, glm, glmnet

I am aware of the http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html packages, but neither of them seems to support Gamma GLMs.

I'd like to utilize elastic net for gamma GLMs in R, what is the easiest way to do it?

(meta: also debating whether this should go on Cross Validated for better responses?)

Comment: With regards to the meta: if this is specifically "how do I code it in R?", then SO is fine (but IMO it wouldn't be offtopic on stats.SE either); if it's "which statistical procedure should I use?", then it's firmly stats.SE territory.

Comment: I think this is for SO -- the OP has indicated that they want to use elastic net (they're not asking whether they should or not).  A couple of thoughts (not an answer really) (1) you could set up the elastic-net penalty (or at least I can see how you would set up ridge or lasso -- I'm not quite sure how to implement elastic-net) by brute force in `optim` or `bbmle::mle2`, but it would probably be quite inefficient; (2) do you have a strong reason to prefer Gamma over a log-Normal analysis (i.e. log-transform response & do penalized least-squares)? Latter would be *much* easier & v. similar ..

Comment: also, sort of "looking for a package" ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HDtweedie package.  Gamma is a special case of the Tweedie distribution with p = 2.  It's a relatively new package, so expect some teething problems.